# Create an extra price attribute (for container deposit)

Tags: product-attribute

I need an extra cost attribute so I can add an extra price per product. I'm creating a beer webshop. In my country we have a deposit on glass bottles. So I need to show the price of a bottle without the deposit. On the final checkout page the deposits must be calculated and showed to the customer.

So the extra cost attribute must be calculated on top of the regular price.

Comment: The bundle workaround solves the problem however the price shows as "From:$1.20 To: $7.19".

Answer (score 0):

Standard magento functionality does not allow to create the attribute which will have the behavior of the price and will be added to the grand total on checkout.

So you need to look for some extension or develop this functionality by yourself.

As a workaround you can [create bundle product](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/creating-a-bundled-product) and assign to it two simple products as required options.
First product will be beer itself, and the second one will be the bottle.

Comment: Hi,

thanks for the clear answer. Why is the Bundle Product option you mention a workaround? Isn't it the solution for my question? Or does are bundle products not meant for this type of bundle?

Comment: Just normally bundle product is used for such kind of products as PC, which customer needs to configure. In your case options should not be configurable. They will exist only for correct price calculation. If it suits you than I used "workaround" wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think https://mage-people.com/product/bottle-deposit-deposit-fees-pfand-extension-for-magento/ this perfect solution you are looking for.
here you can setup custom price as attributed for deposited product.